# Simple value comparison in SQL

Tags: compare

I am trying to compare columns in my database. I have a column for valve size and a column for valve turns. I need to make sure the valve turn value is 3 times the value + 2 of the valve size value with an allowable varience of 1. I.E: a valve size of 6 can return a turn value between 19-21. I am then going to use a does not equal function to flag records that dont meet the criteria.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using MS SQL, you could do something like this to start:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE valveturn BETWEEN valvesize * 3 + 1 AND valvesize * 3 + 3
```

Where table is the name of your table and valveturn & valvesize would need to be the actual column names.

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your concise, accurate and polite answer. I appreciate it!